# How to set the time zone for an event created from an email in Apple mail?

Tags: mail.app, calendar

To create an event in a different time zone than your own in the calendar app, you need to activate Time Zone support in the settings. Once it's activated, you can click on the event's date to reveal the time zone and set it to whatever you want:

[image]

However, when you want to create a new event from an email in Apple Mail by clicking on a date in that email, I see now option to change the time zone (nor do I see a setting that makes that option available):

[image]

The only way I am able to accomplish this is by adding the event in my current time zone, switch to the calendar app, click the event, click the date, and change the time zone.

What better solution is there?